# Why is bread warm at room temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry, temperature

If I buy a loaf of freshly-made bread and leave it out at room temperature for a day or two, when I reach into the bag the air inside is much warmer than the rest of the room. Why?

Comment: Maybe there is some crystallization of organic molecules going on while the bread turns hard. This might be a chemical question after all.

Comment: After reading some more stuff I actually think that crystallization of starch might be the answer to this question. There is a lot of literature about this and it might very well be that it can be sufficiently exothermic to warm the small volume of air in a bag.

Comment: To the above point i also want to include possible exothermic enzymatic reactions by microorganisms also

Comment: It could also be that inside the bag it's humid, and purely through suppressing the slow evaporative cooling of your skin it "feels" warmer. You could put on a thin nitrile glove to control for that.

Comment: (It turned out to be completely bogus, oops)

Comment: Is it *actually* warmer or does it just *feel* warmer? Have you measured the temperature?

Comment: @matt_black did you even read the comment above yours

Answer (score 11):

After reading some more stuff I actually think that crystallization of starch might be the answer to this question. There is a lot of literature about this and it might very well be that it can be sufficiently exothermic to warm the small volume of air in a bag.

Comment: I call for an experiment. Bread, digital thermometer with recording device...

Comment: We need a controlled experiment before speculating. What sort of bread, bag, room? Moreover *measure* the temperature and don't rely on subjective feeling.